# How to apply toggle?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here is my code of html on which i have to apply togle

```
 <div class="contact-links contact-info">
                <ul>
                        <li class="contact-link-list toggle-sub"><a data-toggle-handler="contact-details-2" href="#">Agent Details</a>
                            <ul data-toggle-group="contact-details-2" class="senf hidden">
                                <ul style="float:left">
                                    <li style="margin-right:20px;">Office hours</li>
                                    <li style="margin-right:20px;">Products offered</li>
                                    <li>Languages</li>
                                    <li>Visit Agent Site</a></li>
                                </ul>
                                <ul style='float:left; margin-left:-20px;'>
                                    <li>Mon-Fri 9:00AM-5:00PM</li>
                                    <li>Auto, Home</li>
                                    <li>English, Spanish</li></ul>

                        </ul></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

and here is my code of jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contact-link-list").click(function(){
        ('.senf').slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
```

here is my jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/n7U6b/
please suggest me where i am wrong

Comment: because there is no DOM element with class 'senf'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no element in your example with a class of `senf`. Also you are missing a $ before your selector:

```
$('.senf').slideToggle("fast");
```

**Edit**

Here is an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n7U6b/2/) from your example. You are still missing the `$`, and you have a stray closing `</a>` tag in there, but you also need to add a class of `senf` to the item you want to toggle. For example:

```
<ul data-toggle-group="contact-details-2" class="hidden senf">
```

Comment: i had update the question u can check for fiddle also

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".contact-link-list").click(function(){
        $('.senf').slideToggle("fast");
    });
 });
```

You just missed a $ sign on `'.senf'`

Plus where is the item with class `senf`?? I might have missed it!

Comment: i had update the question u can check for fiddle also

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/z6mV7/ - your fiddle didnt have .senf and you still had no $ before .senf as per above